# Where - Case statement results in ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: oracle, case, where-clause

```
select field1, field2
from table
where
(CASE
           WHEN :P_AccountType =  'B'  THEN  GLCC.SEGMENT2 <  '40000'
           WHEN :P_AccountType =  'P'  THEN  GLCC.SEGMENT2 >= '40000'
ELSE  
           GLCC.SEGMENT2 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' 
END)
```

Cannot see which key word is missing. Plse help. See background below.

User can select Accountype A = Trial Balance Accounts '00000' - '99999' B = BS Accts '00000' -'39999' P = All IS Accts '40000' - '99999' This variable result in a range. So :P_AccountType =B Segment2 should contain all Balance sheet accounts '00000' - '39999' etc. segment2 values are strings

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your prompt reply. Problem here is that there is not such as IF B AND, if users select Account type from a prompt, SEGMENT2 should retrieve < '40000'  Accounts, similarly for P then >= '40000'  accounts should be retrieved. So result of Accounts range to be retrieved is depening of choice selected from DropDownList :AccountType

Answer (score 0):

You can't selectively apply other conditions using a case expression. In this case I think it's specifically complaining when it hits the `<`, `>=` or `between` - they are all wrong, and not what the parser is expecting to see there. (It's expecting another `when` or `else` or `end` for the first two; and `end` for the third.)

You can just use boolean logic instead, something like:

```
select field1, field2
from table
where
   (:P_AccountType = 'B' and GLCC.SEGMENT2 <  '40000')
or (:P_AccountType = 'P' and GLCC.SEGMENT2 >= '40000')
or (:P_AccountType not in ('B', 'P') and GLCC.SEGMENT2 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999')
```

or from your last paragraph, the last line could perhaps be:

```
or (:P_AccountType = 'A' and GLCC.SEGMENT2 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999')
```

I'm not sure if the second condition, for `'P'`, also needs an upper bound; or indeed if the the `B` one needs a lower bound. It's harder to tell with strings. The `A` case might not need its range check at all. Depends on your data though.